Issue with SSL certificate after reinstallation of the server to ubuntu 22.04
I have 3 remote servers in ubuntu, running different dockers across the servers. I have purchased a SSL certificate (*.mydomain.com) and running apache server to route my dockers which are running on a particular port. I have renewed and updated my .crt, .csr, .key certificates with the new ones. Those are working fine in all the servers. All the servers are with Ubuntu 18.04, and due to some manditory upgrade for dockers to work, I have reinstalled one of the server to ubuntu 22.04. Though I have reinstalled the apache server properly and disabled all the firewalls my ssl certificate is not being recognized.
When i use "http://x.x.x.x:5004/test" i could get a reply " I am alive", but I check "https://generic-server-qa.mydomain.com/test" it says url not found. When I hit https://generic-server-qa.mydomain.com/ it is rerouting to http://generic-server-qa.mydomain.com/ and showing apache2 default page.
I have cross checked if there are any changes in /etc/apache2/sites-available/generic-server.conf , paths to certificate files are correctly configured, proxypass and proxypassreverse are also correctly configured.
I have crossed verified A certificate configuration too.
I couldnt understand what is wrong with my SSL certificate configuration and why apache server is not working fine. I am pretty new to these concepts. Any help would be appreciated.
Updated:
Here is my config file
<IfModule mod_ssl.c>
    <VirtualHost _default_:443>
            ServerAdmin webmaster@localhost
            ServerName generic-server-qa.mydomain.com
            #DocumentRoot /var/www/html
            
            ErrorLog /var/log/apache2/error.log
            CustomLog /var/log/apache2/access.log combined
            
            #   SSL Engine Switch:
            #   Enable/Disable SSL for this virtual host.
            SSLEngine on

            SSLCertificateFile      /root/isl.crt
            SSLCertificateKeyFile /root/isl.key

            #   Server Certificate Chain:
            SSLCertificateChainFile /root/islchain.crt

            #   Certificate Authority (CA):
            #SSLCACertificatePath /etc/ssl/certs/
            #SSLCACertificateFile /etc/apache2/ssl.crt/ca-bundle.crt

            #   Certificate Revocation Lists (CRL):
            #SSLCARevocationPath /etc/apache2/ssl.crl/
            #SSLCARevocationFile /etc/apache2/ssl.crl/ca-bundle.crl

            #   Client Authentication (Type):
            #SSLVerifyClient require
            #SSLVerifyDepth  10

            #   SSL Engine Options:
            #SSLOptions +FakeBasicAuth +ExportCertData +StrictRequire
            <FilesMatch "\.(cgi|shtml|phtml|php)$">
                            SSLOptions +StdEnvVars
            </FilesMatch>
            <Directory /usr/lib/cgi-bin>
                            SSLOptions +StdEnvVars
            </Directory>

<Location />
    ProxyPass               http://x.x.92.175:8004/ connectiontimeout=90 timeout=80 nocanon
    ProxyPassReverse        http://x.x.92.175:8004/
</Location>
        </VirtualHost>
        <VirtualHost *:80>
           ServerName generic-server-qa.mydomain.com
           Redirect / https://generic-server-qa.mydomain.com/
        </VirtualHost>
</IfModule>

some outputs:
root@vmi539610:~# sudo apachectl configtest
Syntax OK
root@vmi539610:~# sudo ufw status
Status: active

To                         Action      From
--                         ------      ----
Apache Full                ALLOW       Anywhere                  
Apache                     ALLOW       Anywhere                  
22/tcp                     ALLOW       Anywhere                  
443                        ALLOW       Anywhere                  
80                         ALLOW       Anywhere                  
Apache Full (v6)           ALLOW       Anywhere (v6)             
Apache (v6)                ALLOW       Anywhere (v6)             
22/tcp (v6)                ALLOW       Anywhere (v6)             
443 (v6)                   ALLOW       Anywhere (v6)             
80 (v6)                    ALLOW       Anywhere (v6)             

root@vmi539610:~# apachectl -M | grep proxy
 proxy_module (shared)
 proxy_http_module (shared)
root@vmi539610:~# openssl x509 -in /root/isl.crt -text -noout
Certificate:
    Data:
        Version: 3 (0x2)
        Serial Number:
            a0:02:34:f3:de:32:65:8f:39:df:02:3d:a0:bf:a1:23
        Signature Algorithm: sha256WithRSAEncryption
        Issuer: C = GB, ST = Greater Manchester, L = Salford, O = Sectigo Limited, CN = Sectigo RSA Domain Validation Secure Server CA
        Validity
            Not Before: Jul 11 00:00:00 2024 GMT
            Not After : Aug 10 23:59:59 2025 GMT
        Subject: CN = *.in-sciencelabs.com
        Subject Public Key Info:
            Public Key Algorithm: rsaEncryption
                Public-Key: (2048 bit)
                Modulus:
                    00:b4:65:b1:7c:73:a0:d3:fd:b0:6e:c6:dd:94:3a:
                    26:1e:35:36:e2:82:9b:01:0c:76:37:42:1f:8e:9f:
                    32:b9:b1:ea:68:26:1a:a7:ba:e9:3e:7d:41:67:af:
                    29:bb:fe:42:b6:6e:06:24:d3:4e:97:2d:86:48:8c:
                    c4:93:ad:08:bb:58:fc:84:f7:eb:81:6e:ec:33:a7:
                    2e:b3:09:a9:9d:7e:b3:3d:85:9a:4b:6e:24:83:f8:
                    bf:7b:4c:91:9b:db:2b:e1:ad:bb:7c:97:c0:f4:34:
                    8d:79:cb:bc:98:e3:06:59:a8:95:aa:f7:e7:f2:99:
                    57:f4:3e:18:b4:3a:76:69:b1:a1:be:5d:90:30:93:
                    25:79:04:ee:9e:dd:5a:8e:d2:92:8e:91:8c:5a:58:
                    2b:33:1b:e3:af:55:68:bf:cf:35:62:03:5b:70:f1:
                    e4:25:74:9e:6f:b9:29:9e:f1:11:0f:cf:f5:73:44:
                    56:62:ea:5c:d3:cb:c2:3a:21:cd:29:f0:7c:32:d1:
                    f1:6a:e7:58:35:80:d4:3a:83:6c:d4:e2:57:f0:1b:
                    c0:2f:cf:87:cf:1a:1f:cc:25:de:13:02:0b:1b:b4:
                    78:20:d2:aa:11:c2:b4:99:a9:6d:17:d0:99:07:a5:
                    8c:0a:23:ff:9a:0f:78:59:cb:74:89:a8:c6:39:6d:
                    67:6b
                Exponent: 65537 (0x10001)
        X509v3 extensions:
            X509v3 Authority Key Identifier: 
                8D:8C:5E:C4:54:AD:8A:E1:77:E9:9B:F9:9B:05:E1:B8:01:8D:61:E1
            X509v3 Subject Key Identifier: 
                2F:44:A4:15:B4:AB:D6:5C:8D:71:16:06:16:40:57:FF:71:9E:55:18
            X509v3 Key Usage: critical
                Digital Signature, Key Encipherment
            X509v3 Basic Constraints: critical
                CA:FALSE
            X509v3 Extended Key Usage: 
                TLS Web Server Authentication, TLS Web Client Authentication
            X509v3 Certificate Policies: 
                Policy: 1.3.6.1.4.1.6449.1.2.2.7
                  CPS: https://sectigo.com/CPS
                Policy: 2.23.140.1.2.1
            Authority Information Access: 
                CA Issuers - URI:http://crt.sectigo.com/SectigoRSADomainValidationSecureServerCA.crt
                OCSP - URI:http://ocsp.sectigo.com
            X509v3 Subject Alternative Name: 
                DNS:*.in-sciencelabs.com, DNS:in-sciencelabs.com
            CT Precertificate SCTs: 
                Signed Certificate Timestamp:
                    Version   : v1 (0x0)
                    Log ID    : DD:DC:CA:34:95:D7:E1:16:05:E7:95:32:FA:C7:9F:F8:
                                3D:1C:50:DF:DB:00:3A:14:12:76:0A:2C:AC:BB:C8:2A
                    Timestamp : Jul 11 12:26:03.916 2024 GMT
                    Extensions: none
                    Signature : ecdsa-with-SHA256
                                30:46:02:21:00:F0:14:99:81:F4:7D:81:67:C9:CB:41:
                                43:2F:68:F5:3C:B5:25:43:4E:29:06:3D:49:8F:34:6A:
                                B8:C2:15:53:0C:02:21:00:8F:0F:22:B8:5F:F8:01:5B:
                                18:F9:BF:6F:11:31:3D:1B:EF:8E:32:D5:1A:74:12:12:
                                E8:26:69:CD:45:6E:FA:5D
                Signed Certificate Timestamp:
                    Version   : v1 (0x0)
                    Log ID    : 0D:E1:F2:30:2B:D3:0D:C1:40:62:12:09:EA:55:2E:FC:
                                47:74:7C:B1:D7:E9:30:EF:0E:42:1E:B4:7E:4E:AA:34
                    Timestamp : Jul 11 12:26:03.867 2024 GMT
                    Extensions: none
                    Signature : ecdsa-with-SHA256
                                30:45:02:20:77:85:E5:9F:C2:B0:72:0D:39:94:CD:06:
                                BD:45:B5:99:06:FB:33:9C:5C:2E:63:12:6D:40:76:9C:
                                31:C9:F0:A4:02:21:00:F5:B8:B2:0C:D3:15:4D:8F:9C:
                                B0:F5:3F:6E:24:E6:62:DC:10:41:10:1E:AA:11:D7:AE:
                                A8:B1:06:1D:99:23:70
                Signed Certificate Timestamp:
                    Version   : v1 (0x0)
                    Log ID    : 12:F1:4E:34:BD:53:72:4C:84:06:19:C3:8F:3F:7A:13:
                                F8:E7:B5:62:87:88:9C:6D:30:05:84:EB:E5:86:26:3A
                    Timestamp : Jul 11 12:26:03.839 2024 GMT
                    Extensions: none
                    Signature : ecdsa-with-SHA256
                                30:44:02:20:17:A9:69:F7:5B:82:CE:DD:B2:92:4E:EA:
                                27:71:A9:7B:DF:A1:1A:4C:98:EE:A4:84:17:E0:6A:20:
                                A0:6A:1C:BD:02:20:43:7C:19:8B:16:DF:9F:8A:ED:AD:
                                8B:29:B7:AA:3E:B2:A7:88:C1:B2:5C:26:C8:9F:6C:D4:
                                C7:82:CE:F2:C3:B8
    Signature Algorithm: sha256WithRSAEncryption
    Signature Value:
        d1:e2:36:88:a5:8e:80:66:47:10:24:a0:8a:fd:d5:36:fc:8d:
        b2:d6:37:5f:04:c7:99:a3:12:b4:b6:e9:c8:b6:24:0f:b8:f9:
        bf:ec:28:82:a9:50:ba:28:11:9f:9a:73:53:61:75:cb:f9:e8:
        0c:26:3f:cc:44:29:0f:ec:0f:23:4e:4b:bf:cc:b7:34:25:ac:
        1e:7a:81:53:17:ed:4e:f7:c7:56:bb:8c:15:eb:60:b1:fa:f5:
        db:0f:43:d5:5c:51:db:e9:59:80:e9:f6:d6:0c:ec:03:87:2a:
        9e:64:01:9b:93:85:18:8a:98:d9:f7:32:6b:2f:97:0b:40:03:
        a4:b0:9f:74:11:e0:f4:a8:c0:b5:31:45:c3:85:71:0b:05:dc:
        7e:fb:44:3d:76:7f:19:1a:80:30:08:f8:7e:8c:6d:3d:d7:f4:
        62:bb:28:32:94:68:ff:8e:e3:e7:3f:3e:57:85:83:8e:28:32:
        30:60:0b:e5:b3:23:9a:c6:ca:a6:eb:c9:e8:04:28:f2:25:61:
        2d:c1:3a:eb:c4:c5:35:89:2a:11:7b:41:16:0c:c7:4b:61:f0:
        b8:49:08:cb:05:ec:7c:d0:77:58:10:09:c7:ac:90:7a:e4:5c:
        05:59:a1:1f:86:b7:18:9d:e4:70:3f:d1:2e:4b:bb:c1:44:3b:
        e3:13:36:f7

Apache server was running fine
root@vmi539610:~# tail -f /var/log/apache2/error.log
[Wed Aug 14 05:47:13.149505 2024] [core:notice] [pid 182950:tid 140385529493376] AH00094: Command line: '/usr/sbin/apache2'
[Wed Aug 14 05:49:25.885441 2024] [mpm_event:notice] [pid 182950:tid 140385529493376] AH00493: SIGUSR1 received.  Doing graceful restart
[Wed Aug 14 05:49:25.915637 2024] [mpm_event:notice] [pid 182950:tid 140385529493376] AH00489: Apache/2.4.52 (Ubuntu) OpenSSL/3.0.2 configured -- resuming normal operations
[Wed Aug 14 05:49:25.915661 2024] [core:notice] [pid 182950:tid 140385529493376] AH00094: Command line: '/usr/sbin/apache2'
[Wed Aug 14 05:49:49.723132 2024] [mpm_event:notice] [pid 182950:tid 140385529493376] AH00493: SIGUSR1 received.  Doing graceful restart
[Wed Aug 14 05:49:49.743336 2024] [mpm_event:notice] [pid 182950:tid 140385529493376] AH00489: Apache/2.4.52 (Ubuntu) OpenSSL/3.0.2 configured -- resuming normal operations
[Wed Aug 14 05:49:49.743371 2024] [core:notice] [pid 182950:tid 140385529493376] AH00094: Command line: '/usr/sbin/apache2'
[Wed Aug 14 05:55:57.596676 2024] [mpm_event:notice] [pid 182950:tid 140385529493376] AH00492: caught SIGWINCH, shutting down gracefully
[Wed Aug 14 05:55:57.705397 2024] [mpm_event:notice] [pid 184435:tid 140234531207040] AH00489: Apache/2.4.52 (Ubuntu) OpenSSL/3.0.2 configured -- resuming normal operations
[Wed Aug 14 05:55:57.705585 2024] [core:notice] [pid 184435:tid 140234531207040] AH00094: Command line: '/usr/sbin/apache2'


Are you sure this is an SSL certificate issue and not a server config issue?  Since you don't share your configuration here we can't really help too much.

Also Ubuntu 18.04 is off topic on this site as it is past EOL.

"When I hit https://generic-server-qa.in-sciencelabs.com/ it is rerouting to http://generic-server-qa.in-sciencelabs.com/ and showing apache2 default page." - which means that the certificate is fine, because a working certificate is required for a redirect from https://. As for why the redirect happens and why there is only a default page visible - this has nothing to do with the certificate but instead with the server configuration.

@David DE: because ubuntu 18.04 had EOL, i need to upgrade to ubuntu 22.04 and the problem came here.
